# How to check if file exists in Eiffel

Tags: eiffel

```
feature 

    open_file_sample
        local
            l_file: UNIX_FILE_INFO
            l_path: STRING
        do
            make
            l_path := "/var/log/syslog"
            l_file.update (l_path)
            if l_file.parent_directory.exists and then l_file.parent_directory.is_writtable then
                create l_file.make
            end
             -- AS the above statement doesn't exist!
            check
                syslog_file_exists_and_is_readable: l_file.exists and then l_file.is_readable
            end
        end
```

Is this the proper way to check for file existence in Eiffel?

I was wondering if there is a way not to create 2 objects. I'll complete my check with following statement:

- define path `l_file_path := "/some/path/with_file.log"
- check if parent directory exists and has rights to write into
- create log file

Comment: side comment, see difference between  `is_access_readable` and `is_readable` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use 
{FILE_UTILITIES}.file_exists (the_file_name)

or
(create {RAW_FILE}.make_with_name (the_file_name)).exists

Comment: Thx this gives me the way with {FILE_UTILITIES}

Comment: Actually could be nice to have something like dirname on linux which gives the parent directory of given file, so not having to define in 2 parts a file and its parent folder....

Comment: I would recommend to use the class PATH , it handles Unicode, parent folder, and so on.

Answer (score 2):

The problem when accessing the file system is that the property of a file or directory may have changed between the time you query it and the time you want to use it (even if it's only a small fraction of a second). Because of that, assertions in Eiffel of the form:

```
f (a_file: RAW_FILE)
    require
        a_file.is_writable
    do
        a_file.open_write
```

may be violated. In the Gobo Eiffel libraries, instead of checking whether a file can be opened in write mode before actually opening it, the revert approach was chosen: try to open the file, and check whether it was opened successfully.

```
f (a_pathname: STRING)
    local
        l_file: KL_TEXT_OUTPUT_FILE
    do
        create l_file.make (a_pathname)
        l_file.recursive_open_write
        if l_file.is_open_write then
            -- Write to the file.
            l_file.close
        else
            -- Report the problem.
        end
```

Note that it uses `recursive_open_write`and not just `open_write` so that missing directories in the path get created as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
do
  if not l_file.exists then
    print ("error: '" + l_path + "' does not exist%N")
  else
    ...
```

You can something similar to this

Comment: where does your `file` object come from?

Comment: sry meant to do l_file.exist

Answer (score 0):

My final solution is following, and is subject to critics, I personnaly find it very complicated in comparison to more low level languages and libs (as bash for ex)

```
log_file_path: detachable PATH
        -- Attached if can be created
    local
        l_file: UNIX_FILE_INFO
        l_path, l_parent_dir: PATH
        l_fu: FILE_UTILITIES
    do
        create l_fu
        -- Parent directory check
        create l_path.make_from_string ({APP_CONFIGURATION}.application_log_file_path)
        l_parent_dir := l_path.parent
        if not l_fu.directory_exists (l_parent_dir.out) then
            l_fu.create_directory_path (l_parent_dir)
        end
        create l_file.make
        l_file.update (l_parent_dir.out)
        if not l_file.exists or
            l_file.is_access_writable
        then
            io.putstring ("Error: " + log_file_path_string + " parent directory is not writtable and cannot be created")
            check
                parent_dir_exists_and_is_writtable: False
            end
        else
            Result := l_path
        end
    ensure
        file_name_could_be_created: Result /= Void
    end
```

Comment: replace
   l_fu.directory_exists (l_parent_dir.out) 
by 
   l_fu.directory_path_exists (l_parent_dir)

Why do you use UNIX_FILE_INFO ? You should use directly RAW_FILE